# Model_id Column Leadboard H2O

Tags: python, h2o, automl

I'm not able to understand the models generated by the **H20 automl**!

The output is like this, for example:
`StackedEnsemble_AllModels_1_AutoML_1_20220809_134944`

How can I know which base models used by stacked?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an H2OAutoML object in a variable named `aml`, you can then see the leaderboard by using `aml.leaderboard`. The leaderboard is basically a table of all trained models sorted by some metric (AUC, RMSE, etc).

Stacked ensembles use the models that were trained before them - either all the models or the best model per model family (GBM, GLM, DRF, etc). To see the base models you can use the following:

```py
print(aml.leaderboard) # to see what models were trained

# Let's assume you like the SE model with
# model_id "StackedEnsemble_AllModels_1_AutoML_2_20220809_174830"

# You can retrieve the model by using h2o.get_model:
se = h2o.get_model("StackedEnsemble_AllModels_1_AutoML_2_20220809_174830")

# And then you can list model ids of the base models:
se.base_models
```